# Gitlab : how to fork a private repository from server A to a server B?

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request, git-fork

In a situation where a Gitlab server A has a private project. An other gitlab server B administred by someone else wants (with the authorisation of server A) to fork the private project and be able to make some pull requests on it.
Is this possible ?
For the moment I only managed to import the project from the gitlab server A to the gitlab server B which is not what i want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be forked between servers, so you will need to fork it on server A.

You can always play with mirroring ( [Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) ) but it adds a level of complexity.

Ex:
You mirror project from A into server B. You do all the changes on B, and have another fork on A mirroring the project on B.

Comment: Keep in mind that [Repository Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) is a paid feature.

Comment: Specifically, *pull* mirroring is a premium (paid) feature. Push mirroring is free to everyone. But pull mirroring is likely to be what you want, so @Chiramisu's comment is still apt.

Comment: @Cody Gray Yep, pulling is definitely what would be required in the case of the OP. On a side note, this feature used to be available for Starter and Bronze levels at the time of my post.